# Theoretical CS style math steps

Tags: math-mode, styles

I am interested in reproducing this style of stepwise exposition:

[image: From Bird and de Moor]

This particular example is from Bird and de Moor's Algebra of Programming. This style seems to be common in theoretical computer science papers.

I don't know the name of this style, so I can't effectively search for a package that implements it already.

I've been trying solutions with the `tabular`, `alignat` and `flalign` environments, but I'm not really getting anything I like. My biggest issue is that there seem to be two sets of tabs that alternate from line to line.

I'm using `amsmath` with `fleqn`.

Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calculation` (provided you fix a couple of things) or define your own environment.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{calculation}

\usepackage{showframe}

% generic command
\newcommand{\catam}[1]{\llparenthesis#1\rrparenthesis}

% for csproof
\newenvironment{csproof}
 {\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}}
 {\end{aligned}\end{equation*}}
\newcommand{\pline}[1]{&#1\\}
\newcommand{\eline}[1]{{=}\quad&\quad\{\text{#1}\}\\}

% for calculation
\renewcommand{\Hsep}{0pt}
\makeatletter % fix the error of the package
\AtBeginDocument{\calc@indent\mathindent}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This equation can be verified as follows:
\begin{csproof}
\pline{\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle\cdot\alpha}
\eline{split fusion}
\pline{\langle\catam{h}\cdot\alpha,\catam{k}\cdot\alpha\rangle}
\eline{catamorphisms}
\pline{\langle h\cdot\mathsf{F}\catam{h},k\cdot\mathsf{F}\catam{k}\rangle}
\eline{split cancellation (backwards)}
\pline{\langle
  h\cdot\mathsf{F}(\mathit{outl}\cdot\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle,
  k\cdot\mathsf{F}(\mathit{outr}\cdot\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle
\rangle}
\eline{$\mathsf{F}$ functor}
\pline{\langle
  h\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outl}\cdot\mathsf{F}\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle,
  k\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outr}\cdot\mathsf{F}\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle
\rangle}
\eline{split fusion (backwards)}
\pline{\langle h\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outl},k\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outr}\rangle
  \cdot\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle}
\end{csproof}

This equation can be verified as follows:
\begin{calculation}
\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle\cdot\alpha
\step{split fusion}
\langle\catam{h}\cdot\alpha,\catam{k}\cdot\alpha\rangle
\step{catamorphisms}
\langle h\cdot\mathsf{F}\catam{h},k\cdot\mathsf{F}\catam{k}\rangle
\step{split cancellation (backwards)}
\langle
  h\cdot\mathsf{F}(\mathit{outl}\cdot\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle,
  k\cdot\mathsf{F}(\mathit{outr}\cdot\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle
\rangle
\step{$\mathsf{F}$ functor}
\langle
  h\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outl}\cdot\mathsf{F}\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle,
  k\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outr}\cdot\mathsf{F}\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}\rangle
\rangle
\step{split fusion (backwards)}
\langle
  h\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outl},k\cdot\mathsf{F}\mathit{outr}\rangle
  \cdot\langle\catam{h},\catam{k}
\rangle
\end{calculation}

\end{document}
```

The error of `calculation` is to set `\mathindent` before `\begin{document}`, whereas `amsmath` sets it at that point. The code has the necessary fix to make the `calculation` environment to respect the `fleqn` math indent.

The `showframe` package is only used to add a frame around the text block.

[image]

Comment: I realize now that I should have chosen a simpler example. I'm sorry to have made you type it all out. Thank you.

Comment: @Timtro It was a good occasion for suggesting a few tricks (`\mathit`, mainly).

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently the style of Wim Feijen. It is implemented in the [calculation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/calculation/calculation.pdf) package as the `calculation` environment.